# Gremlin intersection of common vertices

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

I have a query that looks like the following:

`"g.V('0_mr').out().out()"`

```
v[11_i]
v[13_i]
v[22_i]
v[23_i]
v[25_i]
v[28_i]
v[11_i]
v[13_i]
v[19_i]
v[29_i]
```

Vertices `11_i` and `13_i` are common vertices for this traversal. How can filter to simply return the common intersecting vertices?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming your definition of common is "more than one".

If that is the case then you can do this

```
     g.V('0_mr').
       out().
       out().
       groupCount().
       unfold().
       where(select(values).is(gte(2)))
```